# Frontend Bug Reporting plugin for Website Beta Tester

Tags: java, javascript

I am looking for a bug reporting solution that I can embed into my website. I would like allow users to report front end issues directly from the page and be able to capture screen clippings, ideally it would also have some kaptcha to prevent basic spamming. I have an issue tracker, I want to ease the reporting process to encourage reports which can be submitted anonymously.

I haven't yet managed to find something that suits my needs, the tools I have found so far seem to be browser based plugins or web based issue trackers which is not what I am after.

Comment: are you looking for a tool that can be embedded into your program so that the website users can repot the bug..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the answer have pretty good solutions but I went with [UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com) in the end primarily because it was easy to use and I was unaware of some of the products suggested here.

Uservoice will create the js that you need to embed in your page and there are a number of pre configured feedback forms that you can choose from. Uservoice offers the option of providing a screenshot with your submission.

It was also trivial to link uservoice with my issue tracker and configure it to push messages to my issue tracker.

Answer (score 6):

[Usersnap](https://usersnap.com) solves your problem. It delivers visual feedback (screenshot + annotations) and integrates with your existing bug tracker (Have a look at the list here: http://usersnap.com/doc/connect).

It's a small widget which is added to your web page in minutes (just a few lines of Javascript):
[image: Usersnap Widget]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [***Saber Feedback (was BugMuncher)***](https://saberfeedback.com/) or [***Diigo***](https://www.diigo.com/). These can be used for reporting the bugs directly from the Web Page. If you need a complex stuff..!!

> [***Google feedback***](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/index.html) is best choice i believe. It's actually a
> feedback tool currently integrated into Google+. Once you click it, it
> pops up a little toolbox that allows you to **"highlight the
> problem"**.Rather than asking for a screenshot or even using any
> terminology like that, it just talks about highlighting the problem*
> and blacking out personal info. Then it asks you to add a comment,
> preview (using a generated screenshot of the page) and send. Its
> REALLY SIMPLE, Good to use and never makes thing more complex. Typical
> Google stuff..!!

Comment: These tools are what i'm looking for on the front end, but BugMuncher and BugHerd provide me with their backend which I don't want, I already have issue tracking.

Comment: @alex edwards If you are looking for a bug tracker in the front end, just for reporting the bug, i suggest you should build a custom page by your own. Afterall the front end user of a website doesn't need a high end tool. All they need is a better UI

Comment: Yeah, I am now building a custom tool, my use case just seemed common enough that someone would have written one. thanks

Comment: @AlexEdwards I think there must be some other ways to do it..!! Can you just check on this link may help, may be in the future. http://www.jtrac.info/doc/html/features.html

Answer (score 3):

[Bugherd](http://www.bugherd.com/docs/installing-the-sidebar) is one of the best out there, and you can embed it by including some javascript to your website. 
Although it might be wise to build what you want yourself. What you described shouldn't be that hard to build, if you keep it simple.

Comment: Yes its not hard to build, just hoping someone else had done it! Started building something myself